# SQL FULL JOIN syntax

Tags: sql

I'm having a problem getting SQL syntax right. I've got three tables I need to FULL OUTER JOIN, but at first I'm trying to get it working with two of them. Just cannot figure out what's wrong.

This is still working:

```
SELECT SUM(A.charge-A.comp), COUNT(A.id)
FROM A
FULL JOIN init ON (A.house=init.house)
WHERE A.tag='V' AND A.house='first'
```

But when I add init field to selected list, it gives syntax error. So this one is not working anymore:

```
SELECT SUM(A.charge-A.comp), COUNT(A.id), init.resp
FROM A
FULL JOIN init ON (A.house=init.house)
WHERE A.tag='V' AND A.house='first'
```

Any Idea why is this?

Btw. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.

Comment: Please provide the full syntax error message.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with the join.  You need a `group by` because you have aggregation functions with a *non-aggregated* column.  Perhaps you mean:

```
SELECT SUM(A.charge-A.comp), COUNT(A.id), init.resp
FROM A
FULL JOIN init ON (A.house=init.house)
WHERE A.tag='V' AND A.house='first'
group by init.resp;
```

Otherwise, you might want some aggregation function:

```
SELECT SUM(A.charge-A.comp), COUNT(A.id), sum(init.resp)
FROM A
FULL JOIN init ON (A.house=init.house)
WHERE A.tag='V' AND A.house='first'
```